# Aplicativo em AndroidStudio java

Tags: android

Estou progamando um app para android no AndroidStudio, em java e trabalho com banco de dados, usando o SQLite, tem como eu listar as imagens que estão sendo salvas no banco de dados no formato BLOB?

Comment: Se quer saber se é possível a resposta é sim, se quer saber como, tem de nos dizer o que já está feito e qual/onde é a sua dificuldade.

Answer (score 0):

Tem como, mas se você pode salvar imagens no drawable, não tem porque sobrecarregar o SQlite para converter bitmap em blob e depois converter blob para bitmap, ou outras extensões de imagens.